# Using Reflector To Create VisualStudio Project

Tags: c#, reflector

I have a .exe app which I want to understand better - I can see it in reflector

Is there any way to get reflector to create a VS project with the code so I can view it properly in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nothing special is needed, it is built into Reflector, albeit not very discoverable.  Right-click the assembly in the left pane and choose Export.  You'll get a chance to change the output directory.  Click OK and Reflector starts decompiling the code, creating a source file for each individual class.  And creates a .csproj file which you can open in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Jason Bock's [FileGenerator](http://www.codeplex.com/FileGenReflector), it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Denis Bauer's Reflector.FileDisassembler http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx. It works well enough to compile and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yea there is, but it doesn't come cheap 
http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/

I have used it to decompile assembly, but I've never used the feature to decompile it into a project so can't give you a review on that. The quality of the decompiler will match the one in reflector.

They also be some legal issues associated with decompiling exe into project - and source for recompilation, so use it with care.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why did you used it instead reflector? That slamander seems fine, but as reflector was free, until version 6, and very versatile...

Comment: I am just not aware that Reflector had that feature. I agree that it will be a free/if not much cheaper option to do this