# Decompiling assembly using RedGate .Net Reflector

Tags: c#, .net

Recently we were given a task from our client. He has a very old web application (compiled) but he has lost its source code. He want to make a very little change in it. Just a couple of lines to be removed. As we only have dll's, I downloaded RedGate's .Net Reflector 8 and also Reflexil. But none of us know how can we make changes to the code inside the dll and save it back again as the new dll. I know it has to be pretty simple but I have never done anything of that sort earlier. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually install Reflexil?

Comment: I added it as an add-in by clicking tools>add-ins>add

Comment: You might try watching their demo video on how to run it and such http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaWtoCmOGpw

Comment: Just make csproj and use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438309/using-reflector-to-create-visualstudio-project

Comment: Thanks Earlz and Lanorkin. I think I am catching on something. Both the methods seem to be working fine. I will let you know if the changes are reflected in the original assembly. Thanks a million.